# strncpy equivalent of std::copy

Tags: c++, stl

The STL provides **std::copy** but it is tricky to use it with output containers with fixed sizes as there is no bounds checking on the output iterator

So I invented my own, something like below

```
template<class InputIterator , class OutputIterator>
void safecopy( InputIterator srcStart , InputIterator srcEnd , 
                    OutputIterator destStart , OutputIterator destEnd )
{
    while ( srcStart != srcEnd && destStart != destEnd )
    {
        *destStart = *srcStart;
        ++srcStart;
        ++destStart;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::istream_iterator<char> begin(std::cin), end;       
    char buffer[3];

    safecopy( begin, end, buffer, buffer + 3 );     
    return 0;
}
```

Questions:

1. Am I reinventing the wheel here ? Is there an stl algorithm to do what I want.
2. Are there any deficiencies in my **safecopy** , does it work for everything std::copy works for ?

Comment: your `buffer` needs to be 4 bytes wide. Otherwise [buffer, buffer+3] will overflow your buffer.

Comment: @parapura Hmm... nvm. You're right, it's a pointer one past the end.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: Hope you don't mind the edit.  I don't think people were getting the spirit of your question.  `std::string` uses random access iterators, which are easy.  Now the problem is a little tougher to crack.

Comment: @parapura : `std::copy` works with output iterators, your code does not -- it's not possible to form a range from output iterators. That's a pretty big step back IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn: Then again, it conceptually doesn't make sense anyway. If you don't have a fixed-size output range, then you can't overflow that range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me promote my comment to an answer, so I have a bit more space.

First off, your implementation looks good.

Now, why isn't this in the standard? (The new standard adds `std::copy_n`, but that does something different, too.*)

Think about it like this: `strncopy` isn't really a "good" idea; it's just not a *terrible* idea. Since C doesn't have any dynamic data structures, a length-checked version is the best you can do.

But in C++ this doesn't fit nicely into the general idea of dynamic containers: You would rarely want to *overwrite some* elements, but rather *create all* elements, which you do by `std::copy` plus `std::inserter`. `strncpy` is a crutch which requires you to preallocate the destination data structure, but in C++ we can do a lot better than this. With dynamic containers, iterators and inserters, we can copy *anything* without needing to worry about allocation.

In other words, any abstract algorithm that you might conceive should have a better, more specific method of obtaining iterators and iterator ranges (think remove/erase); it is rarely the case that the ultimate *goal* of an algorithm is to only produce an output range that is constrained by some other destination range.

In summary: Yes, you can do that, but you can probably do better.

<sub>*) Though `copy_n` plus `min` of source and destination size could be used to create a bounded copy.</sub>

Comment: Even C++11 introduces std::array which is a compile time fixed size ... is it not ? How is one supposed to use std::copy with it ?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar : Pointers are random access iterators which are output iterators. Why would `std::array<>` be any different to use than any other container?

Comment: @ildjarn What I meant was ... if you use a std::array of fixed size as outputiterator you will need some kind of bound checking and std::copy will not cut it ?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: Typically you would only use `std::array` if you want your entire array to be meaningful, in which case you wouldn't want to copy anything but a matching range into it. If you have variable ranges, you wouldn't use `std::array`, and instead prefer a dynamic container. C++ absolves you from having to carry around needless cruft and magic `MAX_SIZE` placeholders.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: Another thought: `strncpy` only really makes sense for null-terminated strings. In general, it doesn't leave the output **array** in a well-defined state (only the null-terminator saves you). You either use it inside a loop or inside an error-checking conditional. For arbitrary containers, such behaviour isn't very useful: You don't normally want to exit from an algorithm in an indeterminate state. In the edited `std::cin` example, what good is copying a *maximum* number of tokens if you don't know how many tokens you actually copied? Much better to insert into a `vector`!

Answer (score 1):

I would make one minor adjustment to your implementation.  Give it a return value.  Either the final output iterator, or an integer indicating the number of elements copied.

The main use case I can see for your function would be reading fixed size chunks from an input stream and you don't know when it will end.  If it does end, you need some way of knowing that, and you need to know how many elements were copied before it actually ended.  If you know how many elements were copied, and it didn't meet or exceed the size of the output range, that's how you can know it ended.

Comment: Some iterators can't be traversed multiple times, making returning a count the better idea

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You're reinventing the wheel again!

For example, you could use `std::copy` as:

```
std::copy(s.begin(), s.begin() + 3 , buffer);
```

instead of this,

```
safecopy(s.begin(), s.end() , buffer, buffer + 3);
```

The usage of `std::copy` in this way is NOT less safer than your `safecopy`.

Or even better is [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) which comes with C++11:

```
std::copy_n(s.begin(), 3, buffer);
```

This would work even if the argument is not random access iterator.

---

As for when you use `std::vector<char>`, you could use its constructor directly as:

```
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
```

No need of even `std::copy`.

Comment: But that won't handle the case when s is smaller than the buffer right ? There would be invalid iterator access

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: It would handle it as well.

Comment: And what if the source iterators are not random access?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That is not a problem. Because that is not the requirement to begin with. `std::copy` works with input iterator as well.

Comment: @parapura: The end to `copy` is the second iterator you pass. As such, it will work correctly.

Comment: @Nawaz: It's not a problem with `std::copy`, it's a problem with your solution.  `s.begin() + 3`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Oh in that case, `std::copy_n` should help, which comes with C++11.

Comment: @Nawaz: `std::advance` would work already in C++03, but requires a named variable.

Comment: @Xeo: `std::advance` wouldn't work if it is input iterator such as `std::istream_iterator`, because you cannot loop input iterator more than once.

Comment: @Nawaz: Ah, right. I forgot that noisy property of input iterators. However, for `istream_iterator`, just a default constructed one works. :P